# Событие при вставке в поле

Tags: jquery

Есть код:

http://jsfiddle.net/Js2Pn/1/

Если вводить в поле клавишами что-либо, то alert(1) выдаёт. А как сделать так, чтобы ещё срабатывало тогда, когда юзер что-то скопировал и вставил в поле? То есть юзер скопировал букву с другого сайта, вставил в поле и должен так же выйти alert(1).

И так нужно постоянно при копировании и вводе одновременно это делать.

Скопировал -> вставил -> alert(1)

Ввёл с клавиатуры -> alert(1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#test').on('input', function() {
   alert(1); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Js2Pn/3/